# Error While fetching columns from join condition in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having 2 csv files i want to load the csv files into data frames in pyspark while joining 2 files I am not having any issues but while retrieving results I am facing an error please help me this

Deliveries Csv having 21 columns and matches csv having 18 columns

My code looks like below

```
df1=spark.read.csv(r"C:\deliveries.csv",header=True,inferSchema=True)
df2=spark.read.csv(r"C:\matches.csv",header=True,inferSchema=True)
df  = df1.join(df2, df1.match_id == df2.id, how='inner')
df.show(10)
```

> I am getting following error
> Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.

So I tried to increase the size by using following command in pyspark

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", 1000)
```

still same issue iam facing any help appreciated

Comment: @blackbishop i tried but still not working for me

Comment: that's not really an error. it's just a warning and you probably can ignore it

Comment: @mck spark.driver.memory   12g increased size also but result has to display right ?

Comment: @Chanukya unless you're using Spark 3 you should set `spark.debug.maxToStringFields` not `spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields`. (the one mentioned in the warning message you get).